# How to add class/id to image based on its title or alt

Tags: javascript

I have this old website that needs some fixes, but they need to be quick.

Now I have this image with

Iam going to change the source with the following code:

```
$("img").click(function(){
    // Change src attribute of image
    $(this).attr("src", "images/card-front.jpg");
});
```

But I cant select the image, since it is dynamic content.

How do I add a class or ID to this image, based on its title or alt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's created dynamically, listen on `document`. 
Also `.click()` is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```js
$(document).on("click", '[alt="Schwimmbäder"]', function(){
    // Change src attribute of image
    $(this).attr("src", "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Click the image:</p>
<img src="unknown" title="Schwimmbäder" alt="Schwimmbäder">
```

Comment: Iam missing a few lines in my explanation. I understand your solution, but thanks anyways. The problem is that I have an image with no class or ID, but with a title and alt attribute:

<img src="unknown" title="Schwimmbäder" alt="Schwimmbäder">

Question is can I select this IMG based on its title or alt, and then change the source using your snippet?

Comment: @bytris Yes, that's possible. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Targetting title and setting a class to an image and then use that new class to handle click events: this is how you can do it...

```js
$('img[title="imgTitle"]').addClass("newClass");
$('.newClass').click(function(){
       $(this).attr("src", "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/peppers.png");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img width="250" title="imgTitle" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" />
```